# How to avoid the duplication of code in this case?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

My project is about implementing an hyperGraph in java

My hyperGraph contain various type of hyperEdge depending on vertex type that I have

Vertex Type:Image , tags ...

HyperEdge =Homogeneous(relate vertex of same type )/Heterogeneous(relate vertex of different type)

Homogeneous HyperEdge= Image-image HyperEdge/Tag-tag hyperEdge

This is a quickly draw UML diagram

[image]

[image]
this is my code

```
public interface HomogenousHyperedge< T extends Vertex<L>, L> extends Hyperedge {

   public abstract List<T> searchNearstNeighborsVertex(
      Hypergraph hypergraph, T vertex);
}
```

```
public class ImageImageHyperedge implements
   HomogenousHyperedge<ImageVertex, Map<String,Instance>> {

   @Override
   public List<ImageVertex> searchNearstNeighborsVertex(Hypergraph hypergraph,
        ImageVertex vertex) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

the problem is in the ImageImageHyperEdge class I should to know what is the type of  feature based on it I will search the ImageVertex nearest neighbors 
I can't pass it into the  abstract method of the super Interface because TagTagHyperEdge class  don't need it

and if I replace ImageImageHyperEdge class by {featureOneHyperEdge class ,...featureFiveHyperEdge class } (in which I know the feature type)
it will be a duplication of code as it is the same nearest neighbors search algorithm

---

feature= low level feature of an image (color histogram for example) 
I have 5 type of low level feature 
I will use each one to search the nearest neighbors of my current image 
All feature are stocked in a simple textual file
the same algorithm is used to search the nearest neighbors
only the file is changed every time

Comment: I'm not sure I correctly understood what you need, so this might go either way. Can you have a base class BaseFeatureHyperEdge that would implement the search algorithm. And expose some kind o a template method that will be overridden by FeatureOneHyperEdge, FeatureTwoHyperEdge and so on. This template method should only provide the type of feature that the search is based on. Hope it helps?

Comment: @DenisRosca the first idea I got is to use the strategy pattern 
I think it is similar to template pattern 
can you explain more you idea please ?

Comment: I guess I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1):

Your UML design's not good enough. Skip the ugly & difficult-to-read 'styling', show us 'Vertex' as well as 'Edge', and an association diagram;  not your (potentially over-complicated) idea of inheritance.

Your APIs, design & fundamental question are not really clear.  'Hyperedge' classes could represent a single instance of an Edge, and associate the two ends of that;  or they could (if better named) represent an Edge Type, and search the graph globally from a specified Endpoint parameter.

These are complelely different designs, your question is meaningless until you figure the above out.

Either way, Edge.search() doesn't have the right signature. Where VS and VE are start and end vertex-types, and TE is edge-types, it should either be:

```
public class EdgeType {
    public List<EV> getEndpoints (SV startVertex);
}
```

or

```
public class Vertex {
    public List<TE> Vertex.getEdges();
}
public class Edge {
    public EV Edge.getEndpoint();
}
```

The nearest-neighbour algorithm should be implemented using generic types, and then called as required (with exact type-signatures) by the concrete classes.

BTW, when you mention "nearest neighbor";  Neither is it clear if "nearest neighbour" means *directly connected vertex*, which is trivial, or to find the nearest distant (how is distance measured? you don't specify) vertex of a specified type.

Either way, the utility & correctness/ need to implement subtypes of 'Edge' seems unclear. Many graph algorithms find Vertices/Nodes to be interesting and subtype these, but I am less than aware of subtyping (or the utility of subtyping) the edges leading to these.

Last tip:  ditch the complex naming, KISS.  'Vertex' and 'Edge' will help you get a clear, simple, comprehensible & correct design. Save the extra wordage for *after* you've got that.

---

In response to further info from Nawara:

Then it's an EdgeType you've modelled, and when asking 'nearest neighbor' you should take a Start Vertex & return either Edge(s) -- if you need the distance metrics -- or Vertices.

The reference to 'Graph' should be probably implicit from the Vertex parameter.

As far as your EdgeType inheritance heirarchy:  subtypes & inheritance should be defined to follow behavioural characteristics, not the generic types (Vertex types) they reference. The principle for OO class heirarchy design is to model *doing*, not *being*.

In this regard you might have a KnnDistanceEdgeType & FlickrDistanceEdgeType classes, either as ancestors, or, if no other method behaviour needs to be different, as the actual implementing classes. The feature types/classes they're searching for can be set as properties -- with properties & genericized differently,  to answer different Vertex types.

eg.

```
IMAGE_IMAGE_EDGES = new KnnDistanceEdgeType<ImageVertex,ImageVertex>( ImageVertex.class, ImageVertex.class);
TAG_TAG_EDGES = new FlickrDistanceEdgeType<TagVertex,TagVertex>( TagVertex.class, TagVertex.class);
ANY_EDGES = new KnnDistanceEdgeType<Vertex,Vertex>( Vertex.class, Vertex.class);
```

If there is much other behaviour (we haven't defined any, and can't imagine much) in EdgeType, you could move the KNN- and Flickr-distance algorithms off to separate classes. Probably no need.

Remember: in OO, subclass for behaviour, not for existence. And give me a +1 vote!

Comment: I have a complex hyperGraph G=(V,E) , V is the vertex set which may contain different type of vertex (image , tag , locaetion...) and E is the hyperEdge set which also contain different edge type ( edge betwenn images , between tags, between image and tag ) 
the way of finding incidence vertex of each hyperEdge is different according to the hyperEdge type 
for example in case of hyperEdge whose start and end point are image 
vertex I use the knn algorithm ( with euclidian distance) in case of hypeEdge  whose start and end point are tags I use the Flickr distance

Comment: that 's why I think I should use an abstract class `hyperedge` and multiple subclass inherit from it and each one represent a different hyperEdge type

Comment: In which case, it's an EdgeKind or EdgeType -- and you ask it specifying a StartVertex, and answering an Edge or Vertex as the result;  Edge if you need the distance, Vertex if you don't.

Comment: there is an misunderstand , I don't mean by edgeType if it is directed or not I mean EdgeKind 
----------------
indeed an hyperEdge connect more than one vertex this is the man difference from simlpe graph

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you wrote about "feature", I would say that would be appropriate as a field in your ImageImageHyperEdge class.  You can create a FeatureType class with whatever various members that will define it.

```
public class ImageImageHyperedge implements
   HomogenousHyperedge<ImageVertex, Map<String,Instance>> {

   private FeatureType featureType;

   @Override
   public List<ImageVertex> searchNearstNeighborsVertex(Hypergraph hypergraph,
        ImageVertex vertex) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: the feature subclass will inherit the concret implementation but how it will know the feature type?

Comment: Wouldn't the class itself indicate the feature type?  As in, wouldn't FeatureOneHyperEdge indicate that the feature type is "FeatureOne"?

Comment: yes but how the concret implementation in the super Class will know it ?

Comment: I guess I'm not totally following what a "feature" is in the context of your problem...it would probably be helpful if you clarify that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this?

```
public abstract class BaseFeatureHyperEdge {

    @Override
   public List<ImageVertex> searchNearstNeighborsVertex(Hypergraph hypergraph,
        ImageVertex vertex) {   
      // implement nearest neighbor search algorithm
      // and call getFeatureType where you need it.
      // This will allow you to have the search algorithm only in one place. 
      //But make the search based on the feature type;
   }

   protected FeatureType getFeatureType();
}

public class FeatureOneHyperEdge extends BaseFeatureHyperEdge{

    @Override
    protected FeatureType getFeatureType() {
        return new FeatureTypeOne();
    }
}


public class FeatureTwoHyperEdge extends BaseFeatureHyperEdge{

    @Override
    protected FeatureType getFeatureType() {
        return new FeatureTypeTwo();
    }
}
```

Maybe you can try the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)?